# Login fails when using FQDN to access local Windows 10 shares

Tags: windows, networking, login, file-sharing

I have a Windows 10 Professional PC running 20H2 build 19042.685.  I recently reformatted the PC and freshly installed this version.  It was running the same or very similar version prior to the reformat.  It is set up with local accounts (not Microsoft accounts), and uses workgroups.  Prior to the reformat, I was able to access file shares using the FQDN (`\\host.domain.name\share`), as well as the IP and hostname.  Now, I can access the IP and hostname, but the FQDN no longer works.  If I sniff port 445 in Wireshark, I don't get any traffic when accessing the FQDN, but I do when I access the IP and hostname.  If I connect to the FQDN, I get an Audit Failure Event ID 4625 in the Security log, with status `0xC000006D`, sub-status `0x0`.  I am prompted for a username and password.  No matter what username and password I give, it fails.  I am not prompted when I open the IP or hostname.  My router/firewall (Ubiquiti EdgeRouter Lite) is also doing DNS, and registers DHCP leases with DNS, giving the FQDN.

What am I missing?  What can I do to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: What's the error message when you failed to access the share with FQDN? If you Nslookup FQDN, will it return the correct IP address?

Comment: @Candy The error is a login box with "The user name or password is incorrect." at the bottom.  `nslookup` returns the correct IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a setting buried in `System -> Rename this PC (advanced) -> Change... -> More...`: `Primary DNS suffix of this computer`.  Setting this to the appropriate DNS suffix made the login issue go away.